# what does "in terms of" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anyone tell me about the meaning of the sentence?

> The walker presents chains to the compiler in terms of bytecode-level actions

Does it mean:

> The walker presents chains to the compiler, and these chains are in the format of bytecode-level actions?

or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation seems to be correct.

"in terms of" is widely used in programming and computer science when referring to the format and granularity of the underlying information(data). Essentially, it describes the kind of "language" that different software components use to communicate between each other.

The relevant meaning can be found in the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=terms):

> terms:
>   4b) Language of a certain kind; chosen words: spoke in rather vague terms; praised him in glowing terms.

and also

> in terms of:
>   1) As measured or indicated by; in units of: distances expressed *in terms of* kilometers as well as miles

Here is another example of similar usage taken from a software manual:

> Ultimately, however, computers represent everything **in terms of** [= computers speak the language of] binary digits, or bits. ([The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computer-Arithmetic.html))

Answer (score 0):

'in terms of' means, literally, 'using the vocabulary of' or more figuratively 'in the context of'.

In your example, presumably it means 'chains' should be interpreted with respect to the context of byte-code. As to the exact intention, how byte-code actions are to be applied to the situation of the walker and the compiler is up to you and the context, the passage you find that sentence in, to figure out